# JQuery how get css property from HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a jQuery object from an HTML string, then I loop through the elements and try to get their CSS property, but in return I get an empty string.

```
var htmlStr = '<p style="text-align: left;">This first string</p>';
htmlStr += '<p style="text-align: center;">This second string</p>';
htmlStr += '<p style="text-align: right;">This third string</p>';
var itemsContent = $(htmlStr);
for (let i = 0; i < itemsContent.length; ++i)
{
    let align = itemsContent.eq(i).css("text-align");
    ...
}
```

variable `align` allways empty. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me on chrome. what browser are you using?

Comment: The [code](https://jsfiddle.net/u2of5906) works.

Comment: you are declaring and assigning `align` var inside `for`, variables declared with `let` are not accessible outside its scope, are you looking for it inside `for`?

Comment: yes, code is work, problem in other code, thank you for answers

Answer (score 0):

You could just call [Parser#parseFromString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)
and iterate over `p` elements finding who has `text-align`:

```
let parser = new DOMParser()
let domDocument = parser.parseFromString(htmlStr, 'text/html')
let elements = [].slice.call(domDocument.querySelectorAll('p'))

elements.filter(e => e.style.textAlign)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Take note of the console.log and comment.

```
var htmlStr = '<p style="text-align: left;">This first string</p>';
    htmlStr += '<p style="text-align: center;">This second string</p>';
    htmlStr += '<p style="text-align: right;">This third string</p>';
var itemsContent = $(htmlStr);
for (let i = 0; i < itemsContent.length; ++i) {
  let align = itemsContent.eq(i).css("text-align");
  console.log(align); // you can call a function here or re-asign the variable.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work just fine, but just incase i rewrote it with test

```js
var htmlStr = '<p style="text-align: left;">This first string</p>';
htmlStr += '<p style="text-align: center;">This second string</p>';
htmlStr += '<p style="text-align: right;">This third string</p>';
 $(htmlStr).each(function(){
    var align = this.style.textAlign;
    console.log(align);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var htmlStr = '<p style="text-align: left;">This first string</p>';
htmlStr += '<p style="text-align: center;">This second string</p>';
htmlStr += '<p style="text-align: right;">This third string</p>';
var itemsContent = $(htmlStr);
i=0;
for (let i = 0; i < itemsContent.length; ++i)

{
    let align = itemsContent.eq(i).css("text-align");
}
```